# how can i print all the texts in only one line? Python2

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a very long text, how can i write a code to print all the text in only one line.

EX: ���� JFIF  H H  �� C

�� C

I want this:

```
    ����JFIFHH��C      �� C
```

Comment: That doesn't look like a "text", that looks like arbitrary binary data. Which isn't really printable, and may contain "newlines" as part of its actual data.

Comment: You can remove '\n" with .replace() (https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_replace.htm) to keep it in a single line if as mentioned above this is the problem...

Comment: this is a ANSI text Data , it can't be printed in python , you must Write a correct alphabétique Words .else , Python will never print it

Answer (score 0):

Use `,` at the end of the statement

```
print "something ",
print "else something ",
```

Output:

```
something else something
```

Though as the commenter mentioned, it's hard to tell if the text you are trying to print has new lines in it or not